# Should I use angular.js for a multi page property management app?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am a new programmer and I am creating a usual property management app. I have read lots about the advantages of angular.js framework vs creating mvc app with jquery. However I am still not clear of whether to create this app using angular or just use jquery. My requirements: The app will be a multi page app, some views will have lots of ajax requests,(and show, hide, animations etc.) with a relatively medium amount of javascript and some views will have little amount of javascript. Not all views will be directly related.

The biggest advantages that is pulling me to use angular, is the user experience, data binding(app will have many forms) and validation. I would like to finish this app as soon as possible, is it necessary for me to learn angular.js and recreate the app using this framework, or can i just continue to use jquery at all times for dynamic data?

I have very little background in angular, and feel very comfortable using jquery.

Should I switch to the angular framework or just use asp.net mvc with jquery for this multi page app?Thank you!

Comment: Read [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: Have been working with both JQuery and Angular. Personally think that using JQuery quickly becomes a mess due to the detatchement between presentation, styling and logic. So my advise would be to use anything that promotes components: React, Vue, Angular..

Comment: @cYrixmorten I am already in middle of creating app with asp.net mvc, is it necessary for me to change framework?

Comment: I think it just might be worth it in the long run. However as for anything new there is a learning curve and it takes time to grasp and master, so ultimatively will have to be a judgement call by you. Have no experience with asp.core but have the impression that it also is component based, maybe that is closer to what you already know. But again, have not tried it myself so not sure how it works to be honest.

Comment: By the way if you go with a single page client side framework and need a server layer to tie together external APIs etc. Then I can recommend parse-server.

Comment: Oh and finally noticed you refer to angular.js which is soon no longer maintained, if you go down that path you would want to use Angular and not AngularJS. Confusing, I know.

Comment: Do you think its a good idea to go with a single page client side framework, if I have different types of view such as contacts, properties...

Comment: Sorry, just one more question, is angular the same as angular js, just a new version?

Comment: Pages like GMail and Google Maps are single page applications, so think it can work for you too :)

Comment: Angular.js was the first version, then they made Angular 2 which essentially in many ways was an entirely different framework. These days I think they are at Angular 7 or 8. So when talking about AngularJS it is version 1 and Angular is 2+